# Preventing user to access login or signup page if logged in, Firebase auth in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I was trying to prevent user from accessing login and signup page once he is logged in. I was trying to find some solution here or Youtube but didn't manage to find what I was looking for. In meantime I was trying to achieve that on my own and I managed to do it with useEffect hook. I'm not sure if it's best practice so check my code below and If someone knows a better way it would mean a lot to me since I am a beginner and I still have a lot of unknowns. To be clear everything works good, just want to know if it's good practice to navigate with useEffect back to home page if user exists.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserAuthContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <ProtectedHomeRoute>
                <Home />
              </ProtectedHomeRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Routes>
      </UserAuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

This is part of UserAuthContextProvider where I'm setting user onAuthStateChange

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("");
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <userAuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        signUp,
        signIn,
        facebookSignIn,
        logout,
      }}
    >
      {!loading && children}
    </userAuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

And inside Signin component I just used useEffect to check is there is user to redirect back to home

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      navigate("/home");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution could be creating a component as `ProtectedHomeRoute`, doing the opposite thing, similar to your useEffect inside Signin; althought, no need to useEffect.
For example:

```
const PublicRoute = ({children}) => {
   const {user} = useUserAuth()
   return user?<Navigate to='/home'>:children
}
```

So then in your App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserAuthContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={
              <ProtectedHomeRoute>
                <Home />
              </ProtectedHomeRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/" element={<PublicRoute>
            <Signin />
          </PublicRoute>} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<PublicRoute>
             <Signup />
          </PublicRoute>} />
        </Routes>
      </UserAuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Even thought this can be a solution, refreshing page will lead to a data loose (since `user` is set to '' when refreshing). I recommend you using some libraries to change this behaviour, as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [Redux persist](https://openbase.com/js/redux-persist)...

Comment: Thanks mate for solution. How can I handle that with redux? Like storing user in store without use of Context or? Do you have some documentation to share about authing with redux and firebase?

Comment: You can create a Store and use contexts at the same time. For the firebase thing, inside `onAuthStateChanged`, check if `currentUser` is null or not. If not, you could dispatch login, if null, dispatch to initial state (normally, null values). To use contexts and redux [see](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store).